# How to add values in SQLAlchemy when the table has foreign keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am having some issues trying to add values to a table that has some foreign keys. I have the following tables

```
class Actividad(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'actividad'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement="auto")
    nombre = Column(String, unique=True, nullable= False)
    gastos = relationship("Gasto", cascade='all, delete, delete-orphan')
    viajeros = relationship('Viajero', secondary = 'actividad_viajero')

    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre


class Viajero(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'viajero'

    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    nombre = Column(String)
    actividades = relationship('Actividad', secondary = 'actividad_viajero')
    gastos = relationship('Gasto', cascade='all, delete, delete-orphan')

    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre

class Gasto(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'gasto'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    concepto = Column(String)
    valor = Column(Integer)
    fecha = Column(Date)
    actividad = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('actividad.id'))
    viajero = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('viajero.id'))

    def __init__(self, concepto, valor, fecha):
        self.concepto = concepto
        self.valor = valor
        self.fecha = fecha

class ActividadViajero(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'actividad_viajero'

    actividad = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('actividad.id'), primary_key=True)
    viajero = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('viajero.id'), primary_key=True)
```

When I add some values to the `Gasto` table using the code

```
    session.add(Gasto(concepto="consumo",valor=1000,fecha=datetime.strptime('15-12-2020', '%d-%m-%Y'),actividad=1, viajero=1))
    session.commit()
```

I get

```
    session.add(Gasto(concepto="consumo",valor=1000,fecha=datetime.strptime('15-12-2020', '%d-%m-%Y'),actividad=1, viajero=1))
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'actividad'
```

However, if I use

```
    session.add(Gasto(concepto="consumo",valor=1000,fecha=datetime.strptime('15-12-2020', '%d-%m-%Y')))
    session.commit()
```

I do not get errors. I wonder, how can I add values to the arguments `actividades` and `viajero` `house` using SQLAlchemy systaxis?

Comment: `def __init__(self, concepto, valor, fecha):` will not accept a keyword argument `actividad`.

Comment: You are right, but how I can fill the other two arguments?

Comment: Modify your init, or drop it completely and instead use the default provided by SQLA. Or just set the attributes after constructing the object.